# how to convert readonly string[] generic into known object

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to convert a generic `readonly string[]` into an object with known keys. But I encounter the error:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Record<T[number], number>'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Record<T[number], number>'.
```

Code:

```
class ArrayToObject<T extends readonly string[]> {
  constructor (private keys : T) {}

  GET_OBJECT () {
    const all = {} as Record<T[number], number>
    for (const index in this.keys) {
      all[this.keys[index]] = index
    }
    return all;
  }
}
```

What I basically want from the generic is something similar to this:

```
const a = ["a", "b"] as const
const o : Record<typeof a[number], number> = {
  a : 1,
  b : 2
}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhjAvDA2gIjmgNDNAjNAXXghlEigFgAoc6GEGALhgCUBTUAJwBMAeKAE8ADuxAAzeCjABXALZ52XQjlkKlAPiQwA3jRjxmMAIxZ9MPEYBMNAL40awADZwIpAIJcucQQBUQAPJ4AFacUHy%20MOwAHlDsYDykXOxwPOBOgjDQXACWYADmKIRaetQGdFBcMsBQIFwwABTCuQBucHEwANbsgqQsvgCUuvZlMADiAKK%20APoBAEIAUhMAwpENQ6UG5eD0cE5O2jq2JGycdfy%200vKKyqrXmuYG4nWNFTB5PDHvYDBQABY5CAAOm6vQ2jy2eycKH%20gJBPQgKA%20MUIxGQyOiEJGWxgySgMi4PyhAG5zCNbEA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because the type system can only know `T extends readonly string[]` but it cannot infer its elements' type correctly. Defining T as the element type can help the type system to infer it.

Also, the `for...in` statement will result in a string key value. You need to convert it into number or use `Array.keys()` or `Array.entries()` to get the numeric index.

```
class ArrayToObject<T extends string> {
  constructor (private keys : readonly T[]) {}
  GET_OBJECT () {
    const all = {} as Record<T, number>
    for (const [index, value] of this.keys.entries()) {
      all[value] = index // + 1 if you want 1-based
    }
    return all;
  }
}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhjAvDA2gIjmgNDNAjNAXXghlEigFgAoc6GEGALhgCUBTUAJwBMAeKAE8ADuxAAzeCjABXALZ52XQjlkKlAPiQwA3jRjxmMAIxZ9MPEYBMNAL40awADZwIpAIJcucQQBUQAPJ4AFacUHy%20MOwAHlDsYDyk0FwAlmAA5lp61AZ0UFwywFAgXDAAFMKpAG5wcTAA1uyCpCxc7HA84E6CML4ohACUuvY5MADiAKK%20APoBAEIAUhMAwpFlQ9kGueD0cE5O2jq2JGycJfy%20qvKKXBrmBuIl5XmoaTwxODVOMuzEEjBQAAWKQgADpGs1QfF8il2BB1ht7ls9k4UF8fsRkG8YkiRlsYG0oDIuGB4PsANzmEa2IA)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the string union from your readonly string using [type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types), like this:

```
const a = ["a", "b"] as const;

type StringFromReadonlyArray<T extends readonly string[]> = T extends readonly (infer U)[] ? U : string;

const tooMany: Record<StringFromReadonlyArray<typeof a>, number> = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3, // <-- Error: Type '{ a: number; b: number; c: number; }' is not assignable to type 'Record<"a" | "b", number>'.
};

const notEnough: Record<StringFromReadonlyArray<typeof a>, number> = { // <-- Error: Property 'b' is missing in type '{ a: number; }' but required in type 'Record<"a" | "b", number>'.
  a: 1,
};

const justRight: Record<StringFromReadonlyArray<typeof a>, number> = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
};
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhjAvDA2gIjmgNDNAjNAXXghlEigG4BYAKDqgE8AHAUxgGUoAnASzADmAMW4gAtgCVWcACbgANowCC3bnEYAeACoxWADyiswM0t2lywimND6CUhAHxIYO-YeOnzCxjAAU-ADNWbhgAVQBKexgAfjCYAC5rHn4BGnpacmgYKBAQAFk4MEZEqVBuGQ0uW2FRSS9LZVV1DSY2EAD4BxwwAFcxPGCnZABvOhh4RIBGLDGYPESAJhnaceBEgGYcAHotmA0AWn2YAFFVEG5ErRZ2AHJhiZhe-uDKOcSnge5Xtce+z9eAL43GC8UhgECwOAQCC8ARgOB4eTsHLZa4wG6lc4VDBoGAAH1wBG6f0GNwAdHQAWk6JlYOCoMdwT0BAALEqsMoVKopETiKSybwqNSaVqsdqdYnPbhDGD3HZ7Q4nM4XGAABVEbG4THReGBoJgYlBMMEILAqLY6PucHeJK+MCBcx6sDMAEcerwzDJTebbpjyhocfjCdhflKHOTZtaYNNKdSMuAsgArHrQCSwllQdmcyrJQS8uoChpC5qi8VwLqhz4y0YrB4x2vzGBLWN0IA)

That `StringFromReadonlyArray` utility type extracts the string union from your readonly array if possible, otherwise it resolves to the generic `string` type.

Comment: how do i integrate into the class usage?